# Problem with anydpi-v26 when creating launcher icon in Image Asset Studio

Tags: android, android-asset-studio

When creating an launcher icon (Adaptive and Legacy) in a Image Asset Studio with a Clip Art, images are created in the mipmap folder:

[image]

But for anydpi-v26, the standard icon for the foreground does not change, although the background color has changed:

[image]

ic_launcher.xml(anydpi-v26):

```
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@color/ic_launcher_background"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

there are two files in the ic_launcher_foreground folder: ic_launcher_foregraund.xml (new icon) and ic_launcher_foregraund.xml (v24) (standard icon)

Why doesn't he change to a new drawing automatically? Thanks for any answer!

Comment: did you upload your icon as PNG?

Comment: @Ticherhaz Hello! Click res folder -> New -> Image Asset -> Foregraund layer -> Clip Art -> select Icon. Then Next -> file type: PNG -> finish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue. Same solution. For some reason, the old file ic_launcher_foreground.xml is not deleted in the drawable folder when creating the new launcher icon. You end up with two files having the same name. So deleting it (**without safe delete**), solves the problem.

Comment: It is worth to mention, that sometimes if you delete files and recreate them, Android Studio throws resource linkink errors. `Build` -> `Rebuild project` solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I removed the ic_launcher_foreground.xml(v24) file from folder: res/drawable/ic_launcher_foreground/, which remained from the standard icon.

This action solved the problem:

[image]

Comment: I came here with the same problem, however I'm concerned that this "answer" is just a bandaid fix and will cause problems on certain phones/apis. I am not an expert by any means. Any thoughts on the side-effects of this as a solution?

Comment: Well, all it took was me trying this solution to see that it doesn't actually work. There's a lot of files that need that when building.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue because one of my libraries had a launcher icon defined. Bizarrely the app module read the ic_launcher_background from the app module, but the ic_launcher_foreground from the library module.

Answer (score 2):

@aaronmarino's answer is right. The only solution i found to use `ic_launcher_foreground` from app module is to rename it to `ic_launcher_foreground_something.xml`

```
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_background_something"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground_something"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```